# Why Apps Script execution failed only when it is triggered by onEdit event on Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am working on Google Apps Script. I have apps script that I have wrote that is supposed to be executed by `onEdit` event on specific sheet.

onEdit.gs

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var syokuninIchiran = new SyokuninIchiran();
    syokuninIchiran.syncTable();
}
```

When the above is executed by edit on the sheet, this error occurs:

> You do not have permission to call openById. Required privilege: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

But, it works with no problem when the script is triggered from Google Apps Script development window. I call the same code by making a test function as follows:

```
function test(){
  var syokuninIchiran = new SyokuninIchiran();
  syokuninIchiran.syncTable();
}
```

It might be problem for this issue? The spreadsheet's owner is not mine. My account has right to edit as the image below.

[image]

Try1:
I tried to add the scope manually into the manifest file(`appsscript.json`). And I approved the authorization. But, nothing changed. It still have the same error message.

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Simple Triggers can not open files aside from the file it is bound to. For this, you need to use an installable trigger.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Simple Trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions:
>
> They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other files because that would require authorization.

So an installable trigger must be used.

#### Setting up the Installable Trigger:

Follow the `Edit > Current project's triggers` menu item, which will open a new page in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the `+ Add Trigger` button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `onEdit`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `From Spreadsheet`
- Select type of time based trigger: `On Edit`

And press save. This will increase the range of functionality of your edit triggers.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)